# jQuery.validate is ignoring my rule declarations

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have a very simple contact form with fields like this:

```
<label>
    First Name<em>*</em>
    @Html.TextBox("txtFirstName", null, new { tabindex = "1"})
</label>
```

I want this field to be required so I've add some code to document ready:

```
$(function(){
    $("#contactForm").validate({
        rules: {
            txtFirstName: { required: true}
            /* also tried this */
            txtFirstName: "required"
        }
    });
});
```

However, at this point it won't require the field. What seems crazy is that if I add a "required" class attribute like so:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtFirstName", null, new { tabindex = "1", @class="required"})
```

It will validate, but I need more complex rules than just required. I need to check that certain options are chosen in a select list then certain fields should or should not be required.

Comment: Is your `#contactForm` selector correct? Are you getting any errors in the console preventing the validate plugin from hooking to the form?

Comment: The `#contactForm` selector is correct. I know because it does validate with out changing the javascript when I add the "required" class attribute. There are no console errors, my form just gets submitted.

Comment: are you having another field by this name in the form? may be in a tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you have included the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script to your page. This script registers its own `.validate` handler on the form which obviously conflicts with yours. The `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script is used when you have a view model decorated with data annotations to perform validation and those data annotations are translated into HTML5 data-* attributes on the generated input fields. Those HTML5 data-* attributes are then interpreted by the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script which registers a `.validate` handler on the form.

If you want to define your own validation rules and register a custom `.validate` rules you will have to do it manually (as you did) and remove any traces of the built-in unobtrusive validation script from this page.

The reason why validation works when you add the `class="required"` attribute on the input field is because the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` picks it up and it includes it in its own rules when it configures the plugin by registering a `.validate` method on the form.

Comment: you are a smart man. I didn't recall including the unobstrusive script, but it was there. removing it made everything start working as expected.

Comment: Excellent answer. I have spent half of the day determining why that by the time code tried to register my rules, there already exists a rule set for the given form, and it just ignores my rules. Sad part for me is that even if I tried to remove all the `DataAnnotations` that could be possibly associated with my form, I still can't get it working.